# How to extract values from a Pandas DataFrame, rather than a Series (without referencing the index)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to return a specific item from a Pandas DataFrame via conditional selection (and do not want to have to reference the index to do so).

Here is an example:

I have the following dataframe:

```
  Code  Colour  Fruit
0   1   red     apple
1   2   orange  orange
2   3   yellow  banana
3   4   green   pear
4   5   blue    blueberry
```

I enter the following code to search for the code for blueberries:

```
df[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry']['Code']
```

This returns:

```
4    5
Name: Code, dtype: int64
```

which is of type:

```
pandas.core.series.Series
```

but what I actually want to return is the number 5 of type:

```
numpy.int64
```

which I can do if I enter the following code:

```
df[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry']['Code'][4]
```

i.e. referencing the index to give the number 5, but I do not want to have to reference the index!

Is there another syntax that I can deploy here to achieve the same thing?

Thank you!...

Update:

One further idea is this code:

```
df[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry']['Code'][df[df['Fruit']=='blueberry'].index[0]]
```

However, this does not seem particularly elegant (and it references the index).  Is there a more concise and precise method that does not need to reference the index or is this strictly necessary?

Thanks!...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
df.loc[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry','Code'].values[0]
```

Output:

```
5
```

First, use `.loc` to access the values in your dataframe using the boolean indexing for row selection and index label for column selection.  The convert that returned series to an array of values and since there is only one value in that array you can use index '[0]' get the scalar value from that single element array.

Answer (score 3):

Referencing index is a requirement (unless you use `next()`^), since a `pd.Series` is not guaranteed to have one value.

You can use `pd.Series.values` to extract the values as an array. This also works if you have multiple matches:

```
res = df.loc[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry', 'Code'].values

# array([5], dtype=int64)

df2 = pd.concat([df]*5)
res = df2.loc[df2['Fruit'] == 'blueberry', 'Code'].values

# array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5], dtype=int64)
```

To get a list from the numpy array, you can use `.tolist()`:

```
res = df.loc[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry', 'Code'].values.tolist()
```

Both the array and the list versions can be indexed intuitively, e.g. `res[0]` for the first item.

^ If you are *really* opposed to using index, you can use `next()` to iterate:

```
next(iter(res))
```

Comment: It does seem like it is obligatory to reference some form of index at some point though to return an actual value, rather than an array or series.

Comment: No, not if you use `next(iter(res))`. This iterates without explicitly specifying index, although index may be used in the background.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

you can also set your 'Fruit' column as ann index

```
df_fruit_index = df.set_index('Fruit')
```

and extract the value from the 'Code' column based on the fruit you choose

```
df_fruit_index.loc['blueberry','Code']
```

Comment: The question specifically states _**(without referencing the index)?**_, so this does not answer the question that was asked, because this solution sets the column as the index and then references the index.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution: convert `pandas.core.series.Series` to integer!

```
my_code = int(df[df['Fruit'] == 'blueberry']['Code'])
print(my_code)
```

Outputs:

```
5
```